# Visual studio 2010 tools are not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using system windows 7 with 64 bit. I have installed **VS 2010** Ultimate in my system. I could not handle so many things. If i press F12 It is not navigate to the particular definition. And Navigate Bar is missing in top of the page to choose the class objects.

The following image will show the difference,

[image]

Newly installed VS

[image]
why this difference? Is anything wrong what ihave installed? Please Help Me.

Comment: Check what are your shortcut settings. There are configuration for old style (VS 2003) for example. May be this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be because of virus and Trojan  it happens reinstall Visual Studio professional edition instead of Ultimate version i have also faced many problem with Ultimate edition

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. But we should install **Visual Studio 2010 SP1**. Then i restart my system. All menu's are working fine.